# Auto-complete not working in Chrome Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am using Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.
The problem is that the auto-complete doesn't work when writing in the search line, and I have no idea what the problem is.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to disabling of auto fill in browser. so please check the following,

settings---->select Show Advanced Settings----->Under Passwords and forms---->Click Check the box Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click.

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this option is already checked, but still there's no autofilling...